# used horizon instance to store but I got a very bad exception in the browser console.

Tags: webpack, rethinkdb, horizon

I am getting a traceback in the developer console when I try to store a data using horizon locally. Could someone shed a light please?

```
const _messageCollection = _horizon('messages');
_messageCollection.store(message);


WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8181/horizon' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
Subscriber.js:227 Uncaught [object Event]SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:227SafeSubscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:184Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:128Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:102Subject.error @ Subject.js:70socket.onerror @ WebSocketSubject.js:141
```